# Variables assignments are not happening as intended. What am i missing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, global-variables, variable-assignment

I have been working on a project to evaluate baseball statistics. I am working on a program that simulates a full game of baseball. For the program, I have created a function called at-bat that takes in a player's on-base percentage and determines whether or not the player gets on base, or gets out. I have created a while loop that says while outs is not equal to 27, continue the program. However, most of the time, the program gets stuck in an infinite loop, completely ignoring the while condition. I believe that there is some disconnect between what the variable assignment should be and what it actually is, however, I am not sure what I am missing. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

````
import random

first= {"obp": 383, "avg": 310}
second= {"obp": 370, "avg": 295}
third= {"obp": 465, "avg": 313}
fourth= {"obp": 351, "avg": 261}
fifth= {"obp": 281, "avg": 221}
sixth= {"obp": 314, "avg": 210}
seventh= {"obp": 297, "avg": 262}
eighth= {"obp": 337, "avg" : 269}
ninth= {"obp": 317, "avg": 277}
order = [first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth, ninth]

outs=0
total_runs=0
on_base=0
game_log=[]




def at_bat(player):
 x=random.randint(1,1000)
 if player["obp"] >= x:
     print("ON BASE: " + str(on_base))
     return "on_base"
 else:
     print("OUTS: " + str(outs))
     return "out"
     



while outs != 27:
 for a in order:
     if at_bat(a)=="on_base":
         on_base+=1
     else:
         outs+=1



print("Outs = " + str(outs))
print("ON base = " + str(on_base))```
````

Comment: `outs` could increase to __more__ than `27` in your for loop? Try changing the condition to `while outs < 27:`?

Comment: @IainShelvington            That helped alot, the variable was being assigned within the for loop and was not being checked by the while loop like I thought it was. I added an if statement above the first if statement in the for loop that says 
```if outs == 27: break```. Now the program is running as intended. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop goes through each `a` in `order` then checks if it's not equal to outs *once it's gone through the whole list*. Because there is a possibility `outs` gets incremented twice during the `for` loop, you get into an infinite loop as `outs` skips past 27
If you want to stop as soon as `outs` reaches 27, regardless if all items in `order` have been traversed, you can do this

```
i = 0
while outs != 27:
  a = outs[i]
  if at_bat(a)=="on_base":
    on_base+=1
  else:
    outs+=1

  i += 1
  # Return to the first item
  if i == len(outs):
    i = 0
```